# Distributivity of projection in relational algebra

Tags: relation-algebra, data-structure

Does a projection distribute over set difference in relational algebra:

in other words does$$\Pi_a (A-B) = \Pi_aA - \Pi_aB$$

where projection is defined as projecting to a subset of attributes from a relation. For example if we have a relation STUDENTS(name, grade, major), we can project onto the subset of attributes that we are interested in (return a table with the instances from STUDENTS but only the columns that we are projecting on).

Comment: Please provide some more context. What exactly is a 'projection' (to an element(?) $a$) in this context? Can you think about some examples?

Comment: I've edited to hopefully add clarity. it's in the context of data systems that I ask the question

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra), 'relation algebra' means something different from 'relational algebra' (which is the term I'm familiar with in this context), so that tag may need editing. (It's the right tag for this question, but the tag itself seems to be erroneous.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is a subset of the domain of a function $f,$ then $f(A)$ is defined as $\{f(x) : x \in A\}.$

Extending this familiar and convenient abuse of notation, we could denote the projection of an tuple $t$ on a set of attributes $a$ by $\Pi_a(t);$ and then, if $A$ is a set of tuples,
$$
\Pi_a(A) = \{\Pi_a(t) : t \in A\}.
$$

It is **not** generally true that
$$
f(A - B) = f(A) - f(B).
$$
In particular, if $f$ is a constant function, and $A, B,$ and $A - B$ are all non-empty, then this equation is false.

This general recipe for a counterexample applies in particular to functions of the form $\Pi_a.$ I leave the details to you, except to say that a simple example might involve two students named Harry and Hermione who are both very good at Potions. :)